# How to set bean property value from other bean property value

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

For example we have bean **beanA** with string property **propertyA**:

```
<bean name="beanA" class="...">
     <property name="propertyA"><value>some string value </value></property>
</bean>
```

And second bean beanB has also string property propertyB, and I want initialize this property with same value as beanA.propertyA, I thought I need to do something like this:

```
<bean name="beanB" class="...">
     <property name="propertyB"><value>beanA.propertyA</value></property>
</bean>
```

But this is not works, expression beanA.propertyA threated as string value.

Probably this is go against IoC theory and not supported by Spring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [util namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util) has some pretty useful things.

You can use `<util:property-path id="name" path="testBean.age"/>`

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3 you can also use [Spring Expression language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
<bean name="beanB" class="...">
     <property name="propertyB"><value>#{ beanA.propertyA }</value></property>
</bean>
```